# Cypher statement to return data type of entity properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a Cypher query that will return the data type of all properties in a given entity in a Neo4j database. For example, given the following node:

```
CREATE (:Person { name: 'Alice', age: 35, active: true })
```

I'd like to write a query that returns something like this:

```
name: string
age: integer
active: boolean
```

Is there a way to do this in Cypher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apoc.meta.type`, to get the datatype of a property like this:

```
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'Alice', age: 35, active: true })
WITH keys(properties(p)) as keys, properties(p) AS propertyMap
UNWIND keys AS key
RETURN key, apoc.meta.type(propertyMap[key])
```

And like this:

```
CREATE (p:Person { name: 'Alice', age: 35, active: true })
RETURN apoc.meta.types(properties(p))
```

Comment: With Neo4j versions 5.* the APOC function is `RETURN apoc.meta.cypher.types(properties(p))`